# phpMyAdmin shows column value as drop-down when field type is int

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm editing a table via phpMyAdmin and see that the dID column is allowing me to select a value from a drop-down list. I initially set the column as an int.

[image: Data Input]

[image: Table definition]

Why is it doing this?

Comment: You need to make the images smaller

Answer (score 4):

It is probably a **foreign key** (constraint), so the choices you have (values that are allowed) are limited to the values in the referenced table.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a guess, perhaps the dropdown list contains values that are found in that column in pre-existing rows of your table. So if there are values that commonly appear, you can select them instead of having to type them in. But that's only a guess.